# recompile 32-bit native library to get 64-bit native library in linux machine

Tags: native, 32bit-64bit, .so

I have native library file ends with .so which of 32-bit version. We are migrating to 64-bit java version from 32-bit. In this case we also need to compile this 32-bit .so file with 64-bit. Please suggest how to recompile 64-bit .so file using 32-bit .so file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635394/how-to-convert-32-bit-compiled-binary-to-64-bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert 32-bit compiled binary to 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635394/how-to-convert-32-bit-compiled-binary-to-64-bit)

Comment: The above links doesn't answer my question. I need to generate new .so files. I have source files from which need to generate shared libraries. But i don't know how to generate shared libraries from this source files.